# Send invoice data to SAGE 50 Cloud on button click

Tags: javascript, firebase, accounting, sage50

I am currently working on a personal project that consists of a website which displays invoice information in a table, which is pulled from Firebase.
I am using JavaScript to show the data in my table.

This is how I'm populating my table:

```
function getInvoices(){
    var docRef = db.collection("invoices");
    docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

         html = createInvoiceRow(doc.data(),doc.id);
          $('.invoiceTable').find('tbody').append(html);

    });
    jobsDataTable = $('.jobsTable').DataTable({language: { search: "", searchPlaceholder: "Search...", sLengthMenu: "MENU" }, "lengthMenu": [[300], ["300"]]});

  });



  }
```

.

```
    function createInvoiceRow(invoice,id)
      {


  var invoicedate = invoice['value'].toDate();
  var getvaluedate = invoicedate.getDate() + '/' + (invoicedate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + invoicedate.getFullYear();



  html = '<tr id="invoice'+id+'">';
  html += '  <td class="centercheck">'+invoice['jobnumber']+'</td>';
  html += '  <td class="centercheck">'+invoice['price']+'</td>';
  html += '  <td class="centercheck">'+getvaluedate+'</td>';
  html += '</tr>';

  return html;


}
```

Here is where I am struggling, I would like to be able to pass the information of a selected invoice into SAGE 50, like how you add invoices on via the 'Batch Ledger', by clicking a button on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Sage 50 SDK by joining the Sage Developer program or you could use a tool like Zynk to import the file into Sage.

Comment: Are you affiliated with Zynk? Please note that when linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.